# splitで分割した結果をすぐに使用したい（一時的に変数に入れないでも利用できるか）

Tags: python, python3

時刻を表現した文字列を、0時からの経過分数に変更したいと思っています。
具体的には `11:15`であれば、`11 * 60 + 15 = 675` という結果を得たいです。

```
a = ‘11:15’
tmp = a.split(‘:’)
result = int(tmp[0]) * 60 + int(tmp[1])
```

と書いてみましたが、ここで使用するためだけに一時的に変数に置くのも面倒かなと思いました。何かいい方法ありますでしょうか？

Comment: 読みにくくなるだけで良い方法とは言えませんが、`sum(a * b for a, b in zip(map(int, a.split(':')), (60, 1)))` とするなど。

Comment: @metropolis なぜ回答ではなくコメントに書くのでしょうか？信用度もかなり高い方なのでなにか理由があるのかなと

Comment: @Jogenara 良い方法ではない(はっきり言って辻褄合わせの悪手でしかない)からです。

Comment: 面白い方法ですね。mapもzipも知りませんで、ググりながら理解しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = '11:15'
result = (lambda h,m: int(h)*60 + int(m))(*a.split(':'))
print(result)  # 675
```

Comment: a.split(':')の前に '*'を付けるのがポイントですね。よくわかりました。

Comment: イテラブルアンパック演算子 * は重宝しますね。

Answer (score 0):

`split()`で文字列として分割するのでは無く、時間/時刻に関する情報として処理する方法も考えられます。

```
from datetime import *
midnight = datetime.strptime('00:00','%H:%M')

a = '11:15'
result = int((datetime.strptime(a,'%H:%M') - midnight).total_seconds() / 60)

print(result)
```

Comment: datetimeは日付＋時刻のデータと思いますが、時刻のみのデータを扱う型ってあるんでしょうか？

Comment: その名の通り[time オブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects)はあるのですが、これには文字列から変換するメソッドが無いんですね。文字列への変換は出来るのですが。

Answer (score 0):

lambda を使うというアイデアで：

```
a = '11:15'
print((lambda tmp: int(tmp[0]) * 60 + int(tmp[1]))(a.split(':')))
```

一応、tmp を lambda 内のローカル変数に閉じ込めただけの形なのですが、グローバルな名前空間は汚さなくて済むということでよければ。

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` したものをリスト内包表記で処理するのも何かと面倒そうなので
@kunif 氏の回答同様, `datetime` を使った方法です

```py
from datetime import timedelta,datetime

timedelta(**dict(zip(('hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'),
                     datetime.strptime('11:15', '%H:%M').timetuple()[3:6]))
         ).seconds /60
```

---

`datetime.strptime().timetuple()[3:6]` によって, 時, 分, 秒(念の為) の `tuple` を取り出し
`timedelta` のキーワード引数として, キーワードと共に与え
そこから全体の秒数を取り出して 60で割って「分」に直してます
(ていうか長いな…)

---

(追記)

`datetime`版の前に試した, pandas版も記しときます

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_timedelta('11:15' + ':00').seconds/60)
```